# Unable to Access my own website from the Server console

Tags: iis-6

I am having a weird issue hosting my web application. I am able to access the website from any other computer (from outside the network and from within the network) but unable to 
access it from the Server!! (using the browser )

The details are as follows

- Windows Server 2003
- IIS 6.0
- The system has got a private IP and a public ip
- Accessing by Domain name/Public IP from external and intranet clients works fine.
- Accessing by Private IP from the  intranet clients works fine
- Accessing by PrivateIP or localhost  works from the server
- Accessing by **Public IP or Domain name from the server doesn't** work!!

As an extra troubleshooting, I did

`telnet localhost 443` - works

`telnet publicip 443` - doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with our DNS settings. We recently changed from Public IP to Private IP and the DNS reply was somewhat messed up when we tried opening it from the Server!!.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe public IP isn't routeable from your server.

Verify what happens when you try to access publicip:

```
tracert publicip
```

Check your network settings:

```
ipconfig /all
```

Check your socket listenings:

```
netstat -a -n
```

Local firewall rules?

Answer (score 0):

Also, there's always the issue of server loopback, wherein a server cannot resolve a named reference to itself from within the server. Most commonly occurs on intranets, or on SharePoint sites, I've noticed.